# 'Accordion' drop down tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drop-down-menu

Help me please to edit the code. I've chosen OCBorghettiView model for accordion ([source code at GitHub](https://github.com/otaviocc/OCBorghettiView/blob/master/OCBorghettiView/OCBorghettiView.m)).

1. I want tableview unfolding within its view, not all window
   ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUUXF.png))
2. I want all cells being closed (now one cell is always opened)

Answer (score 4):

Hey I have also used Accordion View in one of my app ,but I have used different library.

[Click Here](https://github.com/appsome/AccordionView) to download the library. This will work for you.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: It Works for me also. Nice example

Comment: But it's not tableview.

Comment: You can add tableview as subview for any header.